# Unity+Vuforia how to make front of the 3dmodel always visible

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vuforia

Just like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMjz1jaE1nI) 
I would like to have a red sphere around and always make the camera facing side visible. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the video, the sphere is actually fixed to the content and moves with it.

Look at the yellow sun - it is actually stationary behind the little tree:

[image]

In my view, they have a sphere that is textured inside (normals facing inwards) and so you are looking through the back of the sphere and see the red texture on the inside back.

Comment: oh you're right! Thank you, one more quick question :) How do I reverse the normals?

Comment: The easiest way is to flip the normals in your modelling tool (eg: Maya, 3ds Max, etc). The normal direction is determined by the way a triangle is draw (clockwise vs anticlockwise), so if you have a loaded mesh in Unity, you can flip the normals in script: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ReverseNormals